# Dot product of sparse matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, naivebayes

Im reading implementation of the [Multinomial Naive Bayes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB) and I do not understand how does this following calculation of dot product of the following matrixes work.

```
self.feature_count_ += safe_sparse_dot(Y.T, X)
```

Code can be found [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/feed6c7139f7e680c3f24963c3a9327d821f3c69/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L709)

Where Y.T.shape = (3, 7000) and X.shape = (7000, 27860). How can it work when number of rows in the `Y.T` is not equal to number of columns in `X`? The size of the resulting matrix is (3, 27860) ?? How does it work? What am I missing?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the "Mulitplying a matrix by another matrix" section here: https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html

If you go through the multiplication, you'll see that only the "inner" dimensions have to match (the 7000 in your case)